# euclidean distance for each point in a point cloud

Tags: matlab, point-clouds, euclidean-distance

I want to compute the minimum eucidean distance between each point in one point cloud and all the other points in the second point cloud.
My point clouds are named pc1 and pc2.
Np is a matrix of normal vectors for each point.

sofar I use the following code:

```
dist = zeros(size(pc2,1),1);
sign = zeros(size(pc2,1),1);

for i = 1:size(pc2,1)
     d = (pc1(:,1)-pc2(i,1)).^2 + (pc1(:,2)-pc2(i,2)).^2 + (pc1(:,3) - pc2(i,3)).^2;
    [d, ind] = min(d);
    dist(i,1) = sqrt(d);
    sign(i,1) = Np(ind,:)*(pc2(i,:)-pc1(ind,:))';
end
```

the last bit with "sign" is from [this](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/publications/papers/metro.pdf) paper. I added it because I want to know if my point lies inside or outside the other point cloud. (I received the point clouds from STL files and they represent surfaces)

Since I am working with rather large point clouds around 200.000 to 3.000.000 points the computation takes a while and I was wondering if anyone could suggest optimizations for my code.
Maybe it could be vectorized and I'm not seeing it.
All your suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

**edit:** just to clearify. Each row in my point cloud matrix is a point. the first column is the x-, the second the y-, the third the z-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this in vectorized form, use `pdist2` and `min` as shown below.

```
dmat = pdist2(pc1, pc2);
[dist, ind] = min(dmat);
```

I believe the following will work for sign, but you should verify the results. May have to tweak slightly based on the matrix shapes.

```
sign = sum(Np(ind,:).*(pc2-pc1(ind,:)), 2);
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work with the ammount of points I want to compute. pdist2 wants to create a array that has a size of 90 GB.

Comment: I don't know of a way to compare the distance of that many points simultaneously. Even if you cant do everything at once, perhaps you can partition pc2 into manageable chunks. For example, if you have 1 million points, create a loop that repeats 100 time and consider 10,000 points each loop using the vectorized code above. This should still be significantly faster than looping through every point individually, and you can adjust it such that you are working within your memory constraints.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will try to break my point clouds up in manageable junks.

Comment: Hi Matt, I just wanted to let you know, it worked like a charm. I sliced my point clouds into chunks along the z axis. And now it is a lot faster than before (about 10 times). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [**KdTree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)'s. This is also the approach of [PCL](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__kdtree.html).

With that approach, you basically create a **KdTree** from the reference point cloud, and then do a **nearest neighbor search** for each point from the query point cloud.

This approach will be magnitudes faster than the brute-force approach.